# Extract all case classes from pattern matching using macro in Scala3

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

In Scala2 project I have macro to extract all cases classes from pattern matching.

```scala
sealed trait Adt
case class A(i:Int) extends Adt
case class B(i:Int) extends Adt

def extract(pf: PartialFunction[Adt, Unit]) = ....
```

I can call it:

```scala
extract{
 case A(i) => ...
 case B(i) => ...
}
```

And I will get `List(A, B)`. I was done with `scala.reflect.api.Trees.Transformer`. In Scala3 API has changed I have to do this in a different way. I was trying this approach with recursive calls:

```
val tree = pf.asTerm

def find(tree: Tree) = tree match {
  case c: CaseDef => ... //TODO extract case class
  case i: Inlined => find(i.body)
  case i: Intend  => find(i.underlying)
  case ....
}
```

But it requires to provide pattern matching for all possible types. Is there a easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you use this to find only those types which where used in pattern matching or all subtypes are enough?

Comment: I'm only interested in types explicitly defined in pattern matching

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to parse ADTs manually. I work on one macro-heavy library myself and even with consultations with Scala 3 compiler team I learned that a lot of utilities from Scala 2 macros you have to reimplement by hand for Scala 3 macros. However if you just want an abstraction that handles recursion for you there is `TreeTraverser` in `Quotes`.